# Adding a PHP function using JQuery every time a user clicks add another select field button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to add a php function called `select()` using jquery every time a user clicks on add another select field button is it possible to do this or is there a better way a user can add the php function `select()` every time a user clicks add another select field?

JQuery (plugins.php)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields = 10;
    var x = 1;

    $('.add-another').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();    

        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').append('<?php echo select(); ?>');  
        }

    });
});
```

PHP (input-fields.php)

```
function select(){
    $select = '';
    $select .= '<select name="select[]" class="title">';

    foreach(select_options() as $option){
        $select .= '<option value="'. $option . '">' . $option . '</option>';
    }

    return $select;
}
```

Comment: Why was this question given a negative?

Comment: you should ask [search engine of your choice] about AJAX. that's the way to make a HTTP-request from inside JS, which in return executes serverside PHP.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't work that way. But there is a simple solution. **Just load the php file**...

**Edit**

I should mention that you are supposed to call your function in your php file to make it work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields = 10;
    var x = 1;

    $('.add-another-helper').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();    

        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').load('/input-fields.php');  
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: after load .php files how you will call the function?

Comment: What do you mean call the function in my php file?

Comment: You must call it in the php file itself. Just add select(); to bottom of your php file

Comment: @time.travel1 how you call the function?

Comment: why not just have a class and use params to call it.. so you will have more function (just like api call)

Comment: he just need more select element..
jquery can do that without load php files

Comment: @time.travel1 - Could you be more concrete? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: the select fields are not being added.

Comment: @time.travel1 - You must append them, as ntaloventi mentioned the documentation

Comment: Yes I'm trying to append them but my select fields are generated using php